# replace a pattern with single character n (bash)

Tags: bash

I have come across a strange misfeature: string substitution works unless the substitute is `n`:

```
$ a=-a
$ echo ${a//a/m}
-m
$ echo ${a//a/n}
$ echo ${a//a/l}
-l
$ echo ${a//a/"n"}
$ echo ${a//a/$'n'}
$ echo ${a//a/\n}
$ echo ${a//a/\\n}
-\n
$ echo ${a//a/n/}
-n/
$ echo ${a//a/nnn}
$
```

How do I replace a substring with just `n` ?

Comment: Why do you leave the space between the first slashes empty? The `n` is probably interpreted as a flag; this works: `echo ${a/a/n/}`

Comment: @L3viathan `echo ${a/a/n/}` shows `-n/` rather than `-n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-n` is an option for `echo`. Your command is equivalent of:

```
echo "-n"
```

Which will output empty string.

Use `printf` instead:

```
a='-a'
printf '%s\n' "${a/a/n}"
```

```
-n
```